# Sine Curve on the Y axis

Tags: trigonometry

This is a pretty simple question I have. I am trying to generate a line like this ?

http://i58.tinypic.com/16izj0w.png

Basically I want to rotate the sine curve 90 degrees and have that curve on the Y axis instead of the X axis.

Does anyone know the equation that line above is ? I tried y= asin(x) however that did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try $x = -\sin y$?

Comment: The inverse sine function does not yield your desired result as it is only defined in the "principal branch" $|x| \leq 1$, so as to not be multivalued.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get the entire curve you showed in the form $y=f(x)$, because each $x$ value has several $y$ values above it in the graph. But you can get a portion of the curve with the equation $y = \arcsin(-x)$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$.